# How to use value of one node as a node itself

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<root>
     <node1>value1</node1>
     <node2>something</node2>
     <something>somevalue</something>
<root>
```

How to form a XPath which would fetch the value 'somevalue' in the above XML example?
The tag `something` is itself a value of `<node2>`

In future `<node2>` may have some different value say `anything`
Which would ultimately result in having `anything` as a tag as shown below

```
<node2>anything</node2>
<anything>somevalue</anything>
```

something/anything  tags would be there depending on value of `<node2>`

How to form XPath for above case?

Answer (score 0):

This code contains a couple of ways to do it. The latter uses a single xpath statement:

```
public void DoXML()
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<root><node1>value1</node1><node2>something</node2><something>somevalue</something></root>");

    //Option 1 - two statements
    string nodeName = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("node2").InnerText;
    string value1 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(nodeName).InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(value1);

    //Option 2 - single statement
    string value2 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("node()[name() = ../node2]").InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(value2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath should work:

```
/root/*[name()=/root/node2]
```

It returns a node with the same name as the value of /root/node2.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mentioned that the value which needs be fetched say somevalue is part of some other tag which is fixed like below <something><tag1>**somevalue**</tag1><tag2>xyz</tag2</something> OR <anything><tag1>**somevalue**</tag1><tag2>xyz</tag2></anything>

Answer (score 0):

From comments of the OP it becomes clear that the XML document is more complex:

**Use**:

```
  /*/*[name() = /*/node2]/tag1
```

Or use:

```
  string(/*/*[name() = /*/node2]/tag1)
```

Or use:

```
  /*/*[name() = /*/node2]/text()[1]
```

Or use:

```
  string(/*/*[name() = /*/node2]/text()[1])
```